# Vertically stack density plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

No code for this I am sorry but I am simply trying to get started with a graph type in R with ggplot2 that I am trying to make, which should look like the following (not sure how it's made, this is a screenshot i took):

[image]
should I simply use geom_density + facet_wrap? Or does anybody know of a better way to achieve coding up a graph type like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The article is [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/visualizing-the-game-style-and-shooting-performance-among) and the code is [here](https://github.com/nycdatasci/bootcamp007_project/tree/master/Project1-ExploreVis/Xinyuan_Wu)

Comment: wow great link - appreciate the share

Comment: Look at the `ggridges` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use facet_grid instead of facet_wrap to achieve this, but that is the easiest method in `ggplot2`

Here's a working example:

```
diamonds %>% 
   filter(cut %in% c('Ideal','Premium','Very Good')) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(carat)) + 
   geom_density() + 
   facet_grid(cut ~ .)
```

Should give this result (as of **ggplot** 3.3.0):

[image]